# Can I link Trello tasks (for meetings) with my Outlook calendar?

Tags: trello, outlook

I'm just starting to use Trello to manage my work to do lists and I'm looking at the possiblility of using it to manage a team task we have to perform. As this task involves scheduling a meeting with other members of our organisation, it'd be great if there were a way to have the Trello task linked with the Outlook calendar, so that task appears as an appointment in the calendar. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

So far no this is a requested feature, you can vote up:

https://trello.com/card/icalendar-feed-with-due-dates/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1116

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still looking at this, as it ranks high on Google still. I've been making an Outlook Add-on to do just this: http://www.tailormadesolutions.com.au/trello-outlook-calendar-addon/

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently Trello has an [iCalendar Feed](http://help.trello.com/article/829-using-trello-with-google-calendar) and Outlook can [subscribe to these feeds](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/View-and-subscribe-to-Internet-Calendars-f6248506-e144-4508-b658-c838b6067597#bm2), so you probably just need to mix these two features.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this easy solution that adds the Trello calendar to Outlook:

http://download.cnet.com/Trello-for-Outlook/3000-2124_4-76250068.html